# How to upgrade GHC with Stack

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

The output of

```
stack ghc -- --version
```

is

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

I want to upgrade to GHC 8.

How can I tell Stack to upgrade GHC?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

User dysfun from the IRC answered my question so I will post it here for posterity.

To update GHC that's used to compile a project, go to the project's `stack.yaml` file.

In there is the resolver field. Update that accordingly. Some examples:

```
resolver: ghc-8.0.2
resolver: lts-9.0
resolver: nightly-2015-09-21
```

For my case, I learned from [this webpage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.0) that resolver `lts-9.0` uses GHC 8.0.2.

[Here's more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446558/understanding-haskells-stack-program-and-the-resolver-and-lts-version) on Stack's resolvers.