# upgrading the ghc version being used by haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to update my ghc version installed for haskell stack from version 8.0.2 to 8.2.1 but seems like I am missing something.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ stack --resolver ghc-8.2.1 setup
stack will use a sandboxed GHC it installed
For more information on paths, see 'stack path' and 'stack exec env'
To use this GHC and packages outside of a project, consider using:
stack ghc, stack ghci, stack runghc, or stack exec

[user@localhost ~]$ stack ghci
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci7878/ghci-script
Prelude> :q
Leaving GHCi.
```

I think I need to do some extra step after to update the ghc version of stack but I am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498425/how-to-upgrade-stack-ghc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options.

temporary solution is every time you have to provide the version of ghc while loading stack.

```
ghc --resolver ghc-8.2.1 ghci
```

If you don't give the version of ghc, stack loads the default version.

The second option is permanently configuring the ghc version for stack as default version. Below is the step used for that

```
configure *resolver: ghc-8.2.1* in the file *.stack/global-project/stack.yaml*
```

and restart your stack.

Comment: thank you. I know this solution. I would like to understand if would be possible using configure command.