# How does stack determine which ghc to use?

Tags: ghc, haskell-stack, nixos

My in-path ghc version is 8.4.4, as show by running `$ ghc -- version`.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.4.4.
```

Somehow, however, my `stack` is using a different version, as shown by running `$ stack ghc -- --version`.

```
$ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2.
```

I have no idea where the 8.0.2 of `ghc` is even installed on my system. How is this possible, and how can I update the version of `ghc` my `stack` uses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533610/upgrading-the-ghc-version-being-used-by-haskell-stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it references a resolver (which in turn references a GHC version). This could be a local `stack.yaml` file or the global one at `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`.